# Checking if a newly submitted string is a valid word

Tags: java

I have a string , after changing the positions of letters in the string I will be getting new strings, Here I have to use dictionary and check whether the newly formed string is a meaningful word or not?

How could I do this in java?

Kindly help me!!

Example :
String: CAT
 From this I can get TAC,ACT,CAT etc..

## or

Java program for s "find the meaningful words from a particular word once we jumble it"

Comment: What code have you tried so far to achieve your task?

Comment: Are you sure that you have to use java.util.Dictionary. It is now considered obsolete, deprcated, don't used.

Comment: I think he means "a dictionary" not "the `Dictionary` class".

Answer (score 1):

Create all subsets of a set of letters (which are in the string). This can be done either recursively or iteratively (hint: use a 1 bit if the letter exists in the element and 0 otherwise; you know that a set has 2^n elements, so you merely have to generate all the bits from [0, 1 << set.size()] and use this to construct the set).

Parse each resulting element of this set and check if it is in the dictionary (e.g. you can use HashMaps) using the element string as the key. If you can show some code, I will be able to guide you from there....

**EDIT:**

I misread the question- you want permutations of the string NOT sets. Making all subsets will require you to eliminate elements whose lengths are smaller than the given string, and this is inefficient. So then you will have to approach differently.

Suppose you have "abc". How would you proceed?

```
elem 1 => “a”, remainder => “bc”
1. permute(bc) = {“bc”, “cd”}
2. Add “a” into each location of “bc” (“abc”, “bac”, “bca”) and 
   “cb” (“acb”, “cab”, “cba”)
3. Return this list
```

Now try coding this recursively...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're asking how to check each permutation to see if it is a valid word, and *not* how to actually compute the permutations, you can perform a lookup against a `Set` that includes all of your valid words, like:

```
private static final Set<String> myDictionary = new HashSet<String>();

static {
   //put some values in the dictionary of valid words (or even better:  load it from a file)
   myDictionary.add("CAT");
   myDictionary.add("DOG");
   //...
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> permutations = permute("CAT");
    for (String candidate : permutations) {
        if (myDictionary.contains(candidate)) {
            System.out.println("Found a valid word:  " + candidate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you going to check all n! permutations? It will toooo slow with len > 15

Comment: @RiaD - That sounds like what was being asked for.  What alternative do you propose?  Breaking the dictionary down into distinct subsets grouped by word length, and then for a given input string iterating the subset that corresponds to the input length, checking to see which words are permutations of the input?  Because that should work, but it doesn't really sound like what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool checkisSecondStringValidFromFirst(String str, String checkstr){
    int n=str.length();
    if(n!=checkstr.length())return false;
    char[] cstr=str.toCharArray();
    char[] ccstr=checkstr.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(cstr);
    Arrays.sort(ccstr);
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        if(cstr[i]!=ccstr[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```